# Amazon Athena: Query speed is ~10x slower via ODBC vs. Grafana (same data)

Tags: odbc, amazon-athena

I am using Amazon Athena to query data from a small Parquet data lake (~3 MB).

I have two use cases:

1. A Grafana dashboard as shown below. Here, I use the Amazon Athena plugin to query data from my AWS S3 based Parquet data lake. A query across all dashboard panels takes around 2-3 seconds to complete, with most of this being the 'overhead' transfer back-and-forth between Grafana and Athena. You can see the playground below:
   https://grafana.csselectronics.stellarhosted.com/d/obd2-gps-car/obd2-gps-car?orgId=1

[image]

2. In Excel on Windows 10 64 bit, I'm using the v2 Athena ODBC driver to create an almost 1:1 replica of the Grafana dashboard, but using Pivot table connections to Athena. Each connection uses an identical SQL query as the Grafana dashboard. However, when refreshing a similar number of queries via the Excel dashboard on the same data lake, the processing time is around 20-30 seconds (i.e. 10x longer). Looking at the Athena 'recent queries' I can see that the actual queries take the same time (~0.5 second each, many parallel) whether queried through Grafana or Excel (as expected). In other words, the overhead must be in the Excel/ODBC setup.

Below is the dashboard example:
[image]

I have followed standard guidance for setting up the ODBC driver and I'm using fairly straightforward implementation of the queries in Excel, so I do not understand what drives the difference. Is this simply "to be expected" when using the ODBC integration? If so, that seems like it would almost make the ODBC driver useless for practical applications.

Below is an example query, as used in both Grafana and Excel (this takes ~0.5 sec within the Athena recent queries):

```sql
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(FLOOR(TO_UNIXTIME(t)/2)*2) as Time,
 AVG(latitude) as latitude, AVG(longitude) as longitude 
FROM tbl_3ba199e2_can2_gnsspos 
WHERE date_created 
BETWEEN '2020/10/29' AND '2020/10/29' AND  t 
BETWEEN TIMESTAMP '2020-10-29 15:00:00' AND 
TIMESTAMP '2020-10-29 15:20:00' 
GROUP BY  FROM_UNIXTIME(FLOOR(TO_UNIXTIME(t)/2)*2) 
ORDER BY Time
```

If I just run the above query in isolation within Grafana, it is instantaneous (<0.5s), while in Excel, refreshing just that one connection takes ~5s. I have also verified that the ~5s is consistent if I make the same query in a blank workbook, directly in the ODBC 'advanced' window and then load that to a Pivot table.

Any inputs are welcome!

Comment: Couple options you can try in the ODBC setup that may help.  Under advance there is an option call "Use Result Set Streaming", when checked driver users result set Streaming API when uncheck it uses pagination logic.  Then "Rows To Fetch Per Block" corresponds to number of rows fetch per steam or page.

Comment: I've tried changing those parameters, but without seeing any significant changes in the results. It is also worth noting that when I set up a query from scratch, the "preview" window of the results loads surprisingly fast, but when the data is to be loaded into e.g. a table it takes about 3-5x longer to refresh (despite the table just being 3 observations of signal averages)

Comment: Run the same query locally via the ODBC, excluding Excel - do you observe the same issues? It's key here to either limit this issue to ODBC or Excel and right now, it's not clear.

Comment: I tested the same query in Excel and via pyodbc. In Excel, the refresh takes ~5s, while in Python via pyodbc it takes ~1.2 seconds (of which Athena's recent queries indicates ~0.5 seconds relate to the query). So it seems the issue is not the ODBC driver necessarily, but Excel's ability to fetch the data quickly. I see a similar issue in PowerBI, which is even slower at refreshing the same query (~10 seconds)

Comment: Okay perfect, that narrows it down :) you’re using the same driver for both for sure? Latest Excel version?

Comment: I'm using Excel 2019 and I'm using the latest Amazon Athena ODBC driver for both (v2.0.2.1). I don't have more recent Excel versions, but I did try with the latest Power BI desktop trial on Windows and the extreme overhead issue is replicated there as well - so I do not expect it to be fixed. Maybe it's just "working as intended", albeit that would be rather unimpressive.